# Rendered 3D View does not match Result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I'm new to Blender and Cycles Render and I was setting up a basic test to produce a smooth polished bronze surface.

My understanding is that the Rendered 3D View from the Camera should match the Single Image output however I simply cannot get any objects, lights or planes to render - merely a flat world colour.

The Viewport:
[image: This is My Rendered Viewport]

Rendered Result:[image: This is my Rendered Result]

I've tried various suggestions from other similar queeries (Ensuring I'm in Global View, ensure all objects are Visible to Render, Assign Each Object to a layer) and I can't quite get my head around what's not happening. Apologies if this is an obvious or stupid question as I am new to both Blender and 3D Modelling as a whole.

The Blender File:
[image]

Comment: Your floor is hidden from final render and in render layer settings you forgot to enable "Use Surfaces", thus no solid geometry in render

Comment: You marvellous person you. I've been headbutting various settings to no avail all morning. A boon on your household sir.